# Embedded DocuSign: Set the text field's width to auto or content-fit

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am embedding DocuSign into my application and using it to send the billing documents. I have to adjust the width and height of the DocuSign text field to auto-expending according to the input data. Will it work just by setting the width/height value to auto or `content-fit`?

Example of the code.

```js
const textFiled = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
    documentId: "1",
    height: "content-fit",
    pageNumber: "1",
    value: envelopeArgs.input,
    width: "content-fit",
    xPosition: "80",
    yPosition: "305",
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign Text fields are auto-adjusted by default.

If you avoid the width and height properties the default will be used.

We hope this helps.

Adrian.
DocuSign Developer Support